# Input in thymeleaf, different value and label

Tags: spring, input, label, thymeleaf

I'm quite new to the Thymeleaf and came across some problem that I cannot resolve by myself. I'm creating a view where user will be able to fill the survey, answer to some questions which can be closed (only A,B, C, D allowed) or open (user inputs his own text). I came to the idea that passing letters A, B, C or D as answers (instead of long strings) will be quicker and better for me and sadly I have no idea how to achieve it using inputs in forms  and thymeleaf. For example, this is question :
`which one is better?
(radio box) answer first, 
(radio box) answer second, 
(radio box) answer third, 
(radio box) answer fourth`

All I want to achieve is when user picks for example `answer first` we will get as a value 'A' instead of whole label.

Answer (score 0):

Radio buttons already work as you've described.  The `value` is what is saved to the database and the `<label>` can have whatever text you want (unrelated to the `value`).

```
<label><input name="question1" type="radio" value="A" /> answer first</label>
<label><input name="question1" type="radio" value="B" /> answer second</label>
<label><input name="question1" type="radio" value="C" /> answer third</label>
<label><input name="question1" type="radio" value="D" /> answer fourth</label>
```